# How to find $\theta$ at which $d$ is the maximum possible?

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, physics

I have an equation:

$$d=\dfrac{v\cos \theta}{g}\left(v \sin \theta + \sqrt{v^{2} \sin^{2}\theta + 2gh} \right),\ g≈9.81 \dfrac {m}{s^{2}}$$

How to find $\theta$ at which $d$ is the maximum possible?

Comment: One way would be trying to differentiate $d$ and see what happens. It does look complicated, though.

Comment: However I think that at least some constraints on $v$ and $h$ are necessary.

Comment: The differentiation doesn't seem so bad, there are a lot of constants (assuming $v$ is a constant)

Comment: @rubik I agree. I guessed that $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$. But it is wrong... It only works if $h=0$.

Comment: Using Mathematica the answer (for $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$) is $$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2gh + v^2}}{\sqrt{2gh + 2v^2}}\right)$$ However, the differentiated expression is complicated so there'll be a fair bit of algebra involved. However, @John, this is a standard undergraduate physics problem, so if you have any Classical Mechanics textbooks they should have a treatment of this problem! :)

Comment: @Shaktal Can you advise me a textbook? :)

Comment: @John I have two, Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions by David Morin is a good book for learning how to deal with problems, but for general understanding I'd recommend Classical Mechanics by Tom W.B. Kibble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of your function $d$ w.r.t. $\theta$ is

$$\frac{\partial d}{\partial\theta} = \frac 1 g\left(v\cos \theta\left(
\frac{v^2\sin\theta\cos \theta}{\sqrt{2gh+v^2\sin^2\theta}}+v\cos\theta\right)-v\sin \theta\left(\sqrt{2gh+v^2\sin^2\theta}+v\sin \theta\right)\right)$$

Setting this to zero and solving for $\theta$ (in a specific range such as $[0,\frac\pi 2]$will give you the extremized values. Unless you have a strong liking for high school algebraic manipulation, I would recommend WolframAlpha or a CAS.

Comment: I got: $$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2gh + v^2}}{\sqrt{2gh + 2v^2}}\right),\ \theta \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

Thanks to all! :)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity consider $$d=2v\cos\theta(v\sin\theta+\sqrt{v^2\sin^2\theta+H}).$$ 
$$(d-v^2\sin 2\theta)^2=4v^2\cos^2\theta(v^2\sin^2\theta+H)=v^4\sin^22\theta+4v^2H\cos^2\theta$$
$$d^2-2v^2d\sin 2\theta=4v^2H\cos^2\theta=2v^2H(\cos 2\theta-1)$$
$$2v^2H\cos 2\theta+2v^2d\sin 2\theta=d^2+2v^2H$$ $$d^2-2v^2d\sin 2\theta+2v^2H(1-\cos 2\theta)=0$$ This is a quadratic equation of $d.$ Note that when $d$ reached to its maximum discriminant of this equation should be zero. Therefore, when $d$ is maximum $$4v^4\sin^2 2\theta-8v^2H(1-\cos 2\theta)=0$$ $$(1-\cos 2\theta)(v^2((1+\cos 2\theta)-2H))=0.$$ This gives $$\cos 2\theta=1$$ or $$1+\cos 2\theta=\dfrac{2H}{v^2}$$